# ASP.NET: ObjectDataSource with a Data Access Class and Business Object

Tags: asp.net, objectdatasource

i recently came across this video: [Use the ObjectDataSource with a Data Access Class and Business Object](http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-use-the-objectdatasource-with-a-data-access-class-and-business-object). can anybody link to another resource that explains how to work with ObjectDataSource with a Data Access Class and Business Object? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use ObjectDataSource a lot in our asp.net applications and it comes quite handy when it comes to dealing custom business-objects and their manager classes.

One good thing of the ObjectDataSource (or rather VisualStudio) is that it gives design-time support for your custome B.O.s and their managers, all you have to do is tag your methods and objects with proper attributes.

You can follow these tutorials to learn more about how to deal with ObjectDataSource.

http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials

http://imar.spaanjaars.com/416/building-layered-web-applications-with-microsoft-aspnet-20-part-1